# How can I read and decode AVRO messages from Kafka along with their associated kafka key using Benthos?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, benthos

I am using Benthos to read AVRO-encoded messages from Kafka which have the `kafka_key` metadata field set to also contain an AVRO-encoded payload. The schemas of these AVRO-encoded payloads are stored in Schema Registry and Benthos has a [`schema_registry_decode`](https://www.benthos.dev/docs/components/processors/schema_registry_decode) processor for decoding them. I'm looking to produce an output JSON message for each Kafka message containing two fields, one called `content` containing the decoded AVRO message and the other one called `metadata` containing the various [metadata fields](https://www.benthos.dev/docs/components/inputs/kafka#metadata) collected by Benthos including the decoded `kafka_key` payload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that one can achieve this using a [`branch`](https://www.benthos.dev/docs/components/processors/branch) processor like so:

```yaml
input:
  kafka:
    addresses:
      - localhost:9092
    consumer_group: benthos_consumer_group
    topics:
      - benthos_input

pipeline:
  processors:
    # Decode the message
    - schema_registry_decode:
        url: http://localhost:8081

    # Populate output content field
    - bloblang: |
        root.content = this

    # Decode kafka_key metadata payload and populate output metadata field
    - branch:
        request_map: |
          root = meta("kafka_key")

        processors:
          - schema_registry_decode:
              url: http://localhost:8081

        result_map: |
          root.metadata = meta()
          root.metadata.kafka_key = this

output:
  stdout: {}
```